# Мультитач жесты в Android Emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

Методом научного тыка выяснил, что при зажатии Ctrl появляется рогатая штуковина, при зажатии и перетягивании мыши эта штуковина делает pinch to zoom. Каким образом мне сделать свайп двумя или тремя пальцами? Как в эмуляторе произвести жесты, отличные от pan и pinch? Как поменять положение центра рогатой штуковины? А то она появляется всегда только по центру экрана.